# Lie derivative in xAct

Tags: xact

I'm using xAct for calculation of Lie derivative of the metric g along the vector field $\zeta$:
$$\mathcal{L}_\zeta g_{m n}$$
the metric g is:
$$d s^2=e^{-2 t} d z d \bar{z}-d t^2$$
and $\zeta$:
$$\zeta=U \partial_z+\frac{1}{2} e^{2 t} U^{\prime \prime} \partial_{\bar{z}}+\frac{1}{2} U^{\prime} \partial_t$$
where U = U (z) is holomorphic and the prime denotes differentiation.

I don't know the correct code for the vector $\zeta$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you share at least any code you have tried?